# Copy a subset of column data from one table to another

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables with identical schema.  Let's name them **TestTable** and **TestTableTemp**.  I need to copy just two columns from TestTableTemp to TestTable without disrupting other data.  The rows in TestTable are a subset of those in TestTableTemp.   Let's say the columns that I need to copy are named **Column1** and **Column2** and that they have identical primary keys reference by column **primaryKey**.

---

In mysql I believe this could be done as such or something similar:

```
UPDATE TestTable, TestTableTemp
SET TestTable.Column1 = TestTableTemp.Column1, TestTable.Column2 = TestTableTemp.Column2
WHERE TestTable.primaryKey = TestTableTemp.primaryKey
```

Sqlite does not allow for multiple tables to be defined on the update statement as can been seen in their reference data here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

The best I could come up with is such:

```
UPDATE TestTable SET
Column1 = (select TestTableTemp.Column1 from TestTableTemp, TestTable where TestTable.primaryKey = TestTableTemp.primaryKey),
Column2 = (select TestTableTemp.Column2 from TestTableTemp, TestTable where TestTable.primaryKey = TestTableTemp.primaryKey) 
WHERE EXISTS(select * from TestTableTemp where TestTable.primaryKey = TestTableTemp.primaryKey"
```

---

This gives me a syntax error near "."  I am guessing this is because I cannot reference TestTable in the scalar expressions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I cleaned up the second query a bit.  It seems to just set the Column1 and Column2 to the first row from that column from TestTableTemp.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query for comparison:

```
UPDATE TestTable, TestTableTemp
   SET TestTable.Column1 = TestTableTemp.Column1
     , TestTable.Column2 = TestTableTemp.Column2
 WHERE TestTable.primaryKey = TestTableTemp.primaryKey
```

Here is the working query (I just slightly changed your version):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f3a19/9

```
UPDATE TestTable
SET

  Column1 = ( SELECT TestTableTemp.Column1
              FROM   TestTableTemp
              WHERE  TestTableTemp.primaryKey = TestTable.primaryKey )

 ,Column2 = ( SELECT TestTableTemp.Column2
              FROM   TestTableTemp
              WHERE  TestTableTemp.primaryKey = TestTable.primaryKey )

WHERE EXISTS( SELECT NULL
              FROM   TestTableTemp
              WHERE  TestTableTemp.primaryKey = TestTable.primaryKey )
;
```